# Trying to uninstall elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rhel7

Trying to uninstall elasticsearch.

When I do the following:

```
[root@sys1 user]# rpm -i elasticsearch-6.2.3.rpm
```

I get this:

```
warning: elasticsearch-6.2.3.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID d88e42b4: NOKEY
        package elasticsearch-0:6.2.3-1.noarch is already installed
```

So I then try to do this:

```
[root@sys1 user1]# rpm --erase elasticsearch-6.2.3.rpm
```

But get the following error:

```
error: package elasticsearch-6.2.3.rpm is not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can erase the package as follows:

`rpm --erase elasticsearch-0:6.2.3-1.noarch`